# Critique Request of my leaf logo

Tags: logo, critique

I have a question about spacing

1. The blue leaves - opposite the words 'Blue Tree Logistics', should I add more blue leaves to make the curve longer?
2. Should the word 'Blur Tree Logistics'  be moved further away from the main image?

[image]

Comment: Hi Tiny.B, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and after reading the guidelines I do agree my question has to be more specific.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think from the original Question the one on "i-jO Creative: A creative/design business" is a good, answerable question in terms of does it reflect a particular brand identity. The questions for the rest are entirely opinion based, so while it is a specific question it's much harder to say if a longer curve is needed or not. Especially when we have no context. Why do you think more leaves might be needed? What are you trying to represent? Ask about those things and it will make a much better question. As it stands I'm voting to close as opinion based, I'll retract if its edited.

Comment: Hi, you are right about 'context' because I didn't give that information.  And I think the 'why' and 'what am I trying to represent' are questions I am going to have to think about and that will probably give me my answer.  Thanks for the feedback - much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

A few leads:

- Watch out for the ratio symbol/typography. Right now your symbol is huge so if you had to stick your logo on something small, it would likely be illegible. If you make that line of text bigger, it might become a bit long so putting things on two lines (Blue Tree/Logistics) might be a good thing.
- The gradient on the leaves seems a bit much to my eye, I would make the light end a bit darker so we don't lose definition in the shapes.
- The ellipsis are a bit 90s, I would try to round the tips more, make it look slightly less technical but that depends on who your client is also.
- I would put the leaves a bit further apart from the elipsis to emphasise the idea of growth and momentum.

Comment: Hi Emilie,  Thank you for the feedback - it really has made a difference and I've changed a few things based on your comments  -    [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/zkedQkw.png)

Answer (score 2):

General tips:

- Try and avoid black outlines (LTL steel). They're default and give easy contrast, but I find they also radiate amateurism (the default outline left as is), unless you have a very good reason to introduce them.
- Create a three- to five-colour palette before starting your design, and use *only* colours from that palette. Only introduce black in the palette if you *really* need it.
- Don't overdo the gradients. They're easy and make things instantly go 'pop', but they're easo to overdo or misuse. The current flat-type style also doesn't use them much, apart from drop shadows.

Comment: Thanks - will take definitely take comments into account